# I want to reload a part of a page, after a user has logged in, to display user-specific information. How can I do this using javascript or PHP?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, authentication, reload

At the moment, I look for the content of the element in question, check if it's the correct info and if not, reload the entire page. The downsides of this are the following:

- IE users get stuck in an infinite loop while logging in, because the browser keeps asking if the user wants to resend form data.
- If the user enters the wrong credentials, the page keeps refreshing, because it can't find the correct information in the element that needs to be refreshed, because it relies on the user being logged in.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: have you tried any code

Comment: Right now I use this:

$(document).ready(function() {
 var content = $("#elementToCheck").text();
 if (content == "") {
  location.reload();
 }
});